# What is the purpose of xmalloc poison

Tags: c, malloc

I was reading source code for git. I encounted this `xmalloc` implementation.

```
static void *do_xmalloc(size_t size, int gentle)
{
    void *ret;

    if (memory_limit_check(size, gentle))
        return NULL;
    ret = malloc(size);
    if (!ret && !size)
        ret = malloc(1);
    if (!ret) {
        try_to_free_routine(size);
        ret = malloc(size);
        if (!ret && !size)
            ret = malloc(1);
        if (!ret) {
            if (!gentle)
                die("Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate %lu bytes)",
                    (unsigned long)size);
            else {
                error("Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate %lu bytes)",
                      (unsigned long)size);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }
#ifdef XMALLOC_POISON
    memset(ret, 0xA5, size);
#endif
    return ret;
}
```

I was wondering what is the purpose of this part:

```
#ifdef XMALLOC_POISON
    memset(ret, 0xA5, size);
#endif
```

Comment: Diagnosing which part of the allocated space was actually written after the allocation?

Answer (score 1):

It's a way to easily see if you're using uninitialized memory. If you use memory and the contents all (or much of it) is`0xA5` then you know that the memory haven't been uninitialized and you have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If the macro `XMALLOC_POISON` is defined, the function will not only allocate memory, but also initialize the value in the memory to (what appears to be) an arbitrary garbage value. This can be a useful technique in debugging issues that are caused by uninitialized variables.